# Excel Round up my enter number

Tags: excel, rounding

I enter this value into excel cell 6272316900099889 but excel auto round the value to 6272316900099880.

Why it cannot keep the value in excel?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells

Comment: It looks like your only option is to format the cell as text.

Comment: Try to format particular column to text or string might be float number issue

Comment: [How to stop Excel from formating the 16 digit account number in a way to avoid making the last digit zero?](https://superuser.com/q/634565/241386)